# header image dimensions layout and layout-land

Tags: android, xml

i cant seem to figure out how to get my header to look correctly.. there's either white space in one view or the other.

is there a way to use two separate images with different dimensions?

I either get it looking like this

[screenshot1 http://m4x.co/m/s1.png](http://m4x.co/m/s1.png) [screenshot2 http://m4x.co/m/l1.png](http://m4x.co/m/l1.png)

or.

[screenshot3 http://m4x.co/m/s2.png](http://m4x.co/m/s2.png) [screenshot4 http://m4x.co/m/l2.png](http://m4x.co/m/l2.png)

but.. i want

[screenshotideal1 http://m4x.co/m/s1.png](http://m4x.co/m/s1.png) [screenshotideal2 http://m4x.co/m/l2.png](http://m4x.co/m/l2.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the white space you can use negativ margin in picture style `<img src='some_picture.png' style='margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-10px;'>`.